# draw square without googlemap with 4 coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates

I have a table ,there are 4 lat,long

our table :

```
corner1_lat (Latitude of the southeast corner of the grid box )           40.617055   

corner1_long (Longitude of the southeast corner of the grid box )       -89.461143     

corner2_lat (Latitude of the northwest corner of the grid box )           40.798627   

corner2_long (Longitude of the northwest corner of the grid box)        -89.641881     
grid_size(This is a value, in meters, of the size of the grid )                75
```

This is image . i want to draw a single square with 4 coordiantes without Googlemaps??
Is it possible without google map ??
[image]

Comment: Of course it is possible, but keep in mind that they are not actually squares but curved surfaces on a sphere with a radius of 6378137m.

Comment: ok,what how this is possible..?i searched on google,but ,didn't find anything .

Comment: You can [project the latlng coordinates on to a 2D plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), and draw them on a [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas).

Comment: I tried but not works.because these are coordinates ..we have to use google map. you can look here                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599058/merge-2-google-maps-polygon-line-and-rectangular-into-one